# Why is there a "on se réfère" right after "autres" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

I read this post here on stack exchange about when to use d'autres and des autres, and some parts confused me like:

> Dans ce cas, l’on sait à quels autres l’on se réfère puisque l’on utilise l’article défini.

I know what it means at first, "In this case we know which others we refer. To since we use the definite article"

But I don't get why there's no "que" before "l'on" and "autre"

Wouldn't it be better as

> Dans ce cas, l’on sait à quels autres **que** l'on se réfère puisque l’on utilise l’article défini.

Answer (score 1):

No, the object of "l'on se réfère" is already "à quels autres". See for example, similarly:

> Je sais déjà à quelle destination tu penses pour les vacances.
>
> J'ai vu de quels exploits il est capable.
>
> Je ne sais plus à quelle question je dois répondre.

To be understood as

> Tu penses à une destination pour les vacances. Je sais laquelle.
>
> Il est capable d'exploits. J'ai vu lesquels.
>
> Je dois répondre à une question. Je ne sais plus laquelle.